# Android Intent constructor undefined while starting an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having some issuses while creating an intent to navigate to a different activity in my android app. When I create the intent function, it gives me an error saying

```
The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MapItmeizedOverlay>) is undefined
```

Here's the SelectOptions.java which has the startActivity intent

```
btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MapItmeizedOverlay.class);
            startActivity(intent2);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Please write below code

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Current_Activity.this, MapItmeizedOverlay.class);
startActivity(intent2);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MapItmeizedOverlay.class);
startActivity(intent2);
```

for Starting new Activity on any View click use Current Activity Context  or Application Context instead of View Context because Intent constructor  take Current Context or application context as first parameter

Comment: khan: Thanks. That worked. But it is strange, since I used the syntax I posted in the same project which worked and this one didn't. Any reason for that.

Comment: i think it's not possible because you can see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29 Intent constructor is taking packageContext as first parameter

Comment: @noobcoder The syntax you've shown will never work.  Are you sure it was inside an onClickListener?  The reason is that the onClickListener is itself a class so `this` is a reference to the instance of the listener, not the activity it's contained in.

Comment: Well, It surely is in an OnClickListener but when call a method outside the OnClickListener which has the intent calls.